# can somebody explain the following syntax and how it functions?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, sorting, containers

```
bool isShorter(const string &s1,const string &s2){
return s1.size() < s2.size()
}
```

What is the role of `isShorter` here and how is it being implemented?

```
sort(words.begin(),words.end(), isShorter);
```

Comment: `isShorter` is a comparator - it tells `std::sort` which of the pair of elements should precede the other in the sorted order. In this example, strings are sorted by their lengths, shorter strings first.

Comment: When in doubt, read the docs: [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but the function `isShorter` that is passed as a parameter to `sort` doesnt have or knows any elements exists because it doesnt contain words in it.

Comment: What do you mean? It takes two of them as arguments - that's all it needs to know. `sort` calls it whenever it needs to determine the order of a pair of elements.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik in the `bool isShorter` definition yes it does have two parameters, but in `sort` the arguments arent being supplied to it. does it implicitly supply the argument due to it being a callable object?

Comment: What do you mean the arguments aren't being supplied? `std::sort()` does that when it calls the function... wouldn't be very useful otherwise.

Comment: If you figured it out, consider *accepting* the most helpful answer by pressing the green tick on the left of it, this will mark your question as solved. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isShorter` is called a Comparator. A comparator is callable that takes two elements of a type as input and returns true if first element should come before second element or else returns false.

So here you are sorting the strings by their length.

Comment: but where are the arguments to `isShorter` in `sort(words.begin(),words.end(), isShorter);` how would it know what to compare since we arent passing in anything to it?

Comment: You are passing the `isShorter` function object to `sort` function. In the implementation of `sort` function, isShorter will be called with proper arguments. So that is taken care for you by people who have written `sort` function.

Answer (score 2):

This call of the standard algorithm `std::sort`

```
sort(words.begin(),words.end(), isShorter);
```

sorts strings stored in a container by their length in the ascending order using the function `isShorter` as a comparison function to compare lengths of two strings in the container.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool isShorter( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
    return s1.size() < s2.size();
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "123", "1", "12" };

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), isShorter );

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
123 1 12 
1 12 123
```

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort): The last argument is `comp`:

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the
>   requirements of `Compare`) which returns ​`true` if the first argument is
>   less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second. The signature of the
>   comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```

For your case the Type1 = Type2 = string. Sort algorithm uses this function to determine the ordering.